# Run Visual Studio as current user and debug with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have exactly the same context of [here](https://superuser.com/questions/689995/visual-studio-2012-debug-windows-8).

**The problem:**

I run a local IIS server to develop a website and it works. If I try to debug however it stated "Unable to start debugging on the web server. You do not have permissions to debug the web server process." as explained on this site. It also has the solution on there, run as administrator.

The problem is that I also have to publish the website to a remote computer. I've create a networkmap to the correct folder (drive W). Publishing to this drive only works if I dont run VS as administrator. As admin it gives the error The path 'W:\' does not exist or you do not have access

Now I'd like to do both without having to restart VS everytime in a different mode.

Now I tried the other option in the first error message, which is to run IIS as the same user. I changed the application pool user and now when I look at the taskmanager both devenv.exe and w3wp.exe run as h.delsing, but it still doesnt work without explicitly giving administrator priviledges. Do I need to change something else to run both IIS and VS as the same user?

Another option would be to allow access to W as admin. Strange thing is that if I run another program as admin (totalcommander) I still have access to the W drive. So i have no clue on how to do this.

The same setup worked fine on Windows 7 which uses the same authentication structure as far as I know. Only difference is that Windows 8 is linked to my live account. I sure hope that is not what causing the problem, as I read that Windows is a little sketchy when it comes to what account it is actualy using.

So in short:

1. How can I run IIS and VS as the same user without admin for
   debugging?
2. Or how can I allow access to the W drive as admin from
   VS?

Some ideas ?